# Is there a way to read the output of getStaticProps from NextJS API routes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, next.js, vercel

I need to compute and cache new data at build time that is required by both the frontend and backend API routes. Is there any way to read the static properties generated at build time by API routes? The API routes are publicly accessible, so I can't just pass the data from the frontend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All build artifacts are saved in `.next` folder, that's outside application source, therefore your code won't be able to access it.

If data you're getting in `getStaticProps` is time consuming to compute, I'd save it in some `cache` and then read from this cache in your API routes.

**UPDATE:**
I lied, I played around and it's actually possible to access cached page data, but there are some caveats.

Build artifacts for given page are saved in `.next/server/pages/`. Exported static props are stored in a JSON file, that matches page path. E.g. static props for `/contact` live in `.next/server/pages/contact.json`.

Those files are deleted when you do `yarn build`, therefore you can't simply import them with

```
import data from '../../.next/server/pages/contact.json'
```

in your code, as that will break the build because of your attempt to import nonexistent file.

What you could do, is loading this file this way:

```
const cacheDirectory = path.join(process.cwd(), '.next/server/pages/');
const fileContents = await fs.readFile(cacheDirectory + '/contact.json', 'utf8');
```

This will build just fine and work when you do `yarn start`. But... it won't work when you do `yarn dev`, because this command clears the build folder. To work around that, you could check for `NODE_ENV` value and run this logic in `production` mode only and use some mock data in this scenario.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the response. Any advice on how to cache within the `getStaticProps` call? I'm having trouble finding resources.

Comment: @PhilGabardo please see update to my answer

Comment: Awesome stuff!! I'll give it a try :)